# How to disable passportjs authentication in local

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am testing my MEAN stack based app on my local. For authentication feature i am using passportjs.

But while debugging i have to login every time i restart the server.

Is there a easy configuration which i can do to disable passportjs without chaning much of my code.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with the following piece of code. Only following change was required to skip authentication for my app.

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    var isAuthorised = req.isAuthenticated();

    // TODO remove followoing on production code
    // Set user as authorised in local
    isAuthorised = true;
    req.user = {};
    // id of whichever account you want to load
    req.user._id = '12345whatever';

    if (isAuthorised) {
        return next();
    }

    // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
    res.redirect('/login');
};
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Curious, what do you test with? And how? Because I think there are easier ways to do this, including automatic log in by the test script :)

Comment: Can you show an example of how this can be done with tat script. Also I didn't get the question about testing this.

Comment: Hmm, can't exactly fit it in the comment, so here is what I mean:
https://gist.github.com/zladuric/bee4cb07893d9f3cd840

Comment: I guess the line 'send({username: 'joe', password: 'tester'})' is doing the work of skipping authentication. one liner for what i am doing :)

Comment: Please provide a solution with at least a process.env.NODE_ENV control flow